# What kind of python process to monitor a queueing system like kestrel or rabbitmq?

Tags: python, queue

I'm fairly new to python, and I was wondering what kind of application would you create to constanstly monitor a queueing service like kestrel or rabbitmq?

How would it run, and under what context?  Would it be a simple python script that would have a infinit while loop?

I'm looking for a long running, stable python service that would respond to incoming messages from either rabbitmq or kestrel.   I want this to be as light weight as possible, but stable and something you can rely on to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're wanting to implement an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). The simplest of these are indeed implemented with what's basically a `while True:` (and then having some shutdown handler that can break out of the loop if it's time to exit by request or some such).